# How to get current unix epoch in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, epoch

This is a function provided by `unix_timestamp()`, but it has been deprecated.

```
select unix_timestamp() from table_name limit 1;
unix_timestamp(void) is deprecated. Use current_timestamp instead.
OK
1553706841
```

It suggests to use `current_timestamp()` instead, but it does not give epoch time:

```
select current_timestamp() from table_name limit 1;
OK
2019-03-27 13:14:21.767
```

What is the recommended way to get current unix epoch time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unix_timestamp` with a datetime/date argument in a string format to get the epoch.

```
select unix_timestamp(current_timestamp())
```

Note that `unix_timestamp` function with no arguments has been deprecated since version 2.0, not `unix_timestamp(string date)`.